# High throughput pointcloud viewer (tens of millions)

Tags: linux, data-visualization, 3d

I need to visualize a cloud of 3*10^7 3D points. I need to be able to interactively (>5fps) zoom/move/"fly" through the cloud.

Things I **don't** need / acceptable tradeoffs:

- the viewer trying to figure out surfaces, or interpreting the geometry in any way besides drawing lots and lots of points
- LOD - nope, please draw every pixel in view, thank you
- occlusion culling - nope, please just Z-sort, thank you
- fancy points - nope, just draw a single unantialiased, unshaded pixel, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic tool that I've used successfully with >30 million points: [rscat](https://github.com/ghosh-somnath/rscat)

[image: Screenshot of rscat]